# How to ssh into EC2 instance without PEM key?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have created an amazon Ec2 instance and I am trying to ssh into the server from my local machine. I can do so with the PEM key but even after adding my local machine's public key to the authorized keys, I cannot login without it. It just tells me "Permission denied (publickey)." Here is the trace.

`debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/joelscalera/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [Superuser](http://superuser.com). Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `ssh-agent` to supply your PEM file during ssh.

First, start the ssh-agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

Then add you PEM key to agent

```
ssh-add <pem-key>
```

Now you can ssh without supplying PEM.

Comment: Also you can place the above commands in your profile so that they don't they persist upon reboot

Answer (score 2):

You can add EC2 pem key to ssh

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/key_pair.pem
```